# Is there a way to use `across` together with `group_by` and `mutate`?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with quartile columns

```r
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

set.seed(234)
df = 
tibble(x1 = sample(1:100, size = 100), # simulate data
       y1 = sample(1:100, size = 100),
       z1 = sample(1:100, size = 100)) %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("1"), ~factor(ntile(.x, 4)), # assign to quartiles
                                        .names = "{.col}_q"))
  
head(df)         
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>      x1    y1    z1 x1_q  y1_q  z1_q 
#>   <int> <int> <int> <fct> <fct> <fct>
#> 1    97    94     9 4     4     1    
#> 2    31    66    66 2     3     3    
#> 3    34    43    62 2     2     3    
#> 4    46    57    41 2     3     2    
#> 5    98     3    38 4     1     2    
#> 6    18    37    40 1     2     2
```

For each of these quartile columns, I would like to append the min and the max of the quartile like so:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(x1_q) %>% 
  mutate(x1_q = glue("Q{x1_q} ({min(x1)} - {max(x1)})")) %>% 
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#> # Groups:   x1_q [3]
#>      x1    y1    z1 x1_q          y1_q  z1_q 
#>   <int> <int> <int> <glue>        <fct> <fct>
#> 1    97    94     9 Q4 (76 - 100) 4     1    
#> 2    31    66    66 Q2 (26 - 50)  3     3    
#> 3    34    43    62 Q2 (26 - 50)  2     3    
#> 4    46    57    41 Q2 (26 - 50)  3     2    
#> 5    98     3    38 Q4 (76 - 100) 1     2    
#> 6    18    37    40 Q1 (1 - 25)   2     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Is there a scalable was I can apply this `group_by` `mutate` pattern to all of my quartile columns?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method - loop `across` the `_q` columns, extract the corresponding columns without the `_q` by removing the substring suffix from the column name, and `get` the value ('tmp'), then use one of the formatting functions to append the column values along with the `min` and `max`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(ends_with("_q"),  ~ 
       {
        tmp <- get(str_remove(cur_column(), "_q"))
        str_c("Q", .x, " (", ave(tmp, .x, FUN = min), " - ", 
                 ave(tmp, .x, FUN = max), ")")
        }
  ))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 100 × 6
      x1    y1    z1 x1_q          y1_q          z1_q         
   <int> <int> <int> <chr>         <chr>         <chr>        
 1    97    94     9 Q4 (76 - 100) Q4 (76 - 100) Q1 (1 - 25)  
 2    31    66    66 Q2 (26 - 50)  Q3 (51 - 75)  Q3 (51 - 75) 
 3    34    43    62 Q2 (26 - 50)  Q2 (26 - 50)  Q3 (51 - 75) 
 4    46    57    41 Q2 (26 - 50)  Q3 (51 - 75)  Q2 (26 - 50) 
 5    98     3    38 Q4 (76 - 100) Q1 (1 - 25)   Q2 (26 - 50) 
 6    18    37    40 Q1 (1 - 25)   Q2 (26 - 50)  Q2 (26 - 50) 
 7    56     4    98 Q3 (51 - 75)  Q1 (1 - 25)   Q4 (76 - 100)
 8     1    17    27 Q1 (1 - 25)   Q1 (1 - 25)   Q2 (26 - 50) 
 9    68    99    73 Q3 (51 - 75)  Q4 (76 - 100) Q3 (51 - 75) 
10    92    65    16 Q4 (76 - 100) Q3 (51 - 75)  Q1 (1 - 25)  
# … with 90 more rows
```

---

Or loop over the `names` in `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2_dfc(names(df)[4:6], names(df)[1:3], 
    ~ df %>%
          group_by(across(all_of(.x))) %>%
          transmute(!! .x := glue::glue("Q{.data[[.x]]} ({min(.data[[.y]])} - {max(.data[[.y]])})")) %>% ungroup ) %>% bind_cols(df[1:3], .)
# A tibble: 100 × 6
      x1    y1    z1 x1_q          y1_q          z1_q         
   <int> <int> <int> <glue>        <glue>        <glue>       
 1    97    94     9 Q4 (76 - 100) Q4 (76 - 100) Q1 (1 - 25)  
 2    31    66    66 Q2 (26 - 50)  Q3 (51 - 75)  Q3 (51 - 75) 
 3    34    43    62 Q2 (26 - 50)  Q2 (26 - 50)  Q3 (51 - 75) 
 4    46    57    41 Q2 (26 - 50)  Q3 (51 - 75)  Q2 (26 - 50) 
 5    98     3    38 Q4 (76 - 100) Q1 (1 - 25)   Q2 (26 - 50) 
 6    18    37    40 Q1 (1 - 25)   Q2 (26 - 50)  Q2 (26 - 50) 
 7    56     4    98 Q3 (51 - 75)  Q1 (1 - 25)   Q4 (76 - 100)
 8     1    17    27 Q1 (1 - 25)   Q1 (1 - 25)   Q2 (26 - 50) 
 9    68    99    73 Q3 (51 - 75)  Q4 (76 - 100) Q3 (51 - 75) 
10    92    65    16 Q4 (76 - 100) Q3 (51 - 75)  Q1 (1 - 25)  
# … with 90 more rows
```

Comment: I'm amazed for `get()` working like this with dplyr. Wow!

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own `myntile` function and just use `across` as usual. Below `myntile` is based on  `ntile`, `cut` and some string manipulation.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

set.seed(234)

myntile <- function(x, n) {
  
  q <- ntile(x, n)
  rng <- as.character(cut(x, n))
  rng2 <- str_replace_all(rng, "[0-9\\.]+", function(x) round(as.numeric(x), 0)) %>%
    str_replace(",", " - ") %>%
    str_replace("]", ")")

  paste0("Q", q, " ", rng2)
}

df = 
  tibble(x1 = sample(1:100, size = 100), # simulate data
         y1 = sample(1:100, size = 100),
         z1 = sample(1:100, size = 100)) %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("1"), ~ myntile(.x, 4), # assign to quartiles
                .names = "{.col}_q"))

head(df)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>      x1    y1    z1 x1_q          y1_q          z1_q        
#>   <int> <int> <int> <chr>         <chr>         <chr>       
#> 1    97    94     9 Q4 (75 - 100) Q4 (75 - 100) Q1 (1 - 26) 
#> 2    31    66    66 Q2 (26 - 50)  Q3 (50 - 75)  Q3 (50 - 75)
#> 3    34    43    62 Q2 (26 - 50)  Q2 (26 - 50)  Q3 (50 - 75)
#> 4    46    57    41 Q2 (26 - 50)  Q3 (50 - 75)  Q2 (26 - 50)
#> 5    98     3    38 Q4 (75 - 100) Q1 (1 - 26)   Q2 (26 - 50)
#> 6    18    37    40 Q1 (1 - 26)   Q2 (26 - 50)  Q2 (26 - 50)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>